# Python-telegram-bot - CommandLine Handler not getting invoked

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created a Python Telegram bot and registered two command handlers. The issue is that the `hello` command handler is not working.

I tried changing the group of that handler to `group=2`, still `hello` does not get invoked when I use `/rtd`.
Unable to figure out the issue.

```
def mybot():
  print("dispatcher created.")
  updater = Updater(token=my_token)
  dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

  dispatcher.add_error_handler(error_callback)
  dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
  dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('rtd', hello, pass_args=True))
  dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.command, unknown))

  print("handlers added.")
  updater.start_polling()
  updater.idle()
  pass

def hello(bot, update, cmd):
    print("hello handler", cmd)
    pass

def start(bot, update):
  bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="bot start!")
  pass

def unknown(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="unknown stuff.")
    pass

def error_callback(bot, update, error):
    try:
        raise error
    except TelegramError:
        print("Telegram Error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("bot started.")
    mybot()
```

Comment: Two considerations. 
1. `hello` function use `print` instead of `bot.send_message`, where you are expecting the output?

2. I see some indent issue in your code. That's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you named the parameters of the `hello` function prototype wrong. The name of the parameter that passes the command arguments *must* be `args`. You named it `cmd` instead.

See the documentation in this regard:
[image: Screenshot of pass_args parameter documentation]

Source: https://ptb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.commandhandler.html

This behaviour is the same for all `pass_*` handler arguments.